# mysql inserts new record where record was just deleted

Tags: mysql, insert

I am having a problem with insert in mySQL after deleting a record. The newly inserted record gets inserted before the other records, in the place that the previous record was deleted.

So, if I have three records like so:

```
SnippetNum  Snippet
1             #1
2             #2
3             #3
```

If I delete record #1, the next record gets inserted like so

```
SnippetNum   Snippet
4             #4
2             #2
3             #3
```

which is messing up how my records are displayed in a checkedListBox

Here is the code for displaying items in the checkedListBox

```
       private void RefreshCheckedListNoteSnippets() {
        AnesthNoteSnippets.Refresh();
        checkedListNoteSnippet.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < AnesthNoteSnippets.List.Length; i++) {
            string command = "SELECT Snippet FROM anesthnotesnippet WHERE SnippetNum = " + AnesthNoteSnippets.List[i].SnippetNum + " ORDER BY SnippetNum ASC";
            string snippet = DataCore.GetScalar(command);
            if (snippet != String.Empty) {
                checkedListNoteSnippet.Items.Add(snippet, false);
            }
         }
      }
```

And here is my insert into code:

```
public static void Insert(string snippet) {
    string command = "INSERT INTO anesthnotesnippet (Snippet)" +
        " VALUES ('" + snippet + "')";
    DataCore.GetScalar(command);

}
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: This doesn't matter. You can retrieve them in any order you want.

Comment: Check your RefreshCheckedListNoteSnippets, you are getting 'i' times your snippets with a WHERE and ORDER ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, rows have no guaranteed intrinsic sort order in the tables, the DBMS is free to put them where it wants.

If you need them sorted in a specific way, that's something you do on extraction, which you already appear to have in your `select` statement.

But, since you're only doing one snippet at a time anyway (making the `order by` superfluous), it looks like it will come down to the order specified by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AnesthNoteSnippets.List.Length; i++)
```

*That's* where you need to be concentrating your focus, it's likely that `AnesthNoteSnippets.List` is not sorted the way you want.

Check into the `AnesthNoteSnippets.Refresh()` call to ensure that the list is appropriately sorted on refresh.

Comment: Yes, you were correct paxdiablo thanks. The problem arose from another method that was retrieving the data table prior to my refresh method. I had to add "ORDER BY SnippetNum" in my Refresh method like so:

Comment: string command ="SELECT * FROM anesthnotesnippet ORDER BY SnippetNum";
            DataTable table = DataCore.GetTable(command);
            List = new AnesthNoteSnippet[table.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
                List[i] =new AnesthNoteSnippet();
                List[i].SnippetNum = PIn.Long(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                List[i].Snippet = PIn.String(table.Rows[i][1].ToString());
            }.............Sorry I can't format that so it's easier to read